# Intellij/Android Studio: Blank list of imports

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, algolia

```
@Serializable
    data class Contact(
        val firstname: String,
        val lastname: String,
        val city: String,
        override val objectID: ObjectID
    ) : Indexable

    fun doSomething() {
        val contact = Contact("Jimmie", "Barninger", "New York", ObjectID("myID"))
        val s = Contact.serializer()
    }
```

I'm trying to import `serializer()` here, but I'm getting a blank list of imports:
[image]

Has anyone else come across this issue? I tried invalidating caches too with no success, and tried in both IntelliJ and AS.

For context, `Indexable` comes from the Algolia library

Comment: Does horizontal scroll work here (Shift + mouse wheel)? Are you able to resize the popup?

Comment: Can you attach the list of your imports and dependencies? What IDE and Kotlin IDE plugin version do you use?